# Find the highest number in each column of an HTML table and highlight it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following `HTML` page with a dynamic `bootstrap table`. For simplicity and for understanding, below is a sample table.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Person 1</th>
        <th scope="col">Person 2</th>
        <th scope="col">Person 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Type 1</th>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>34</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Type 2</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Type 3</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>90</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to know which is the highest number in every column and highlight that number. For example, for the first column, 12 is the highest number and thus highlight 12, second column 65 is the highest number and thus highlight that. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Is this a static table? Do you get the data from an API call? If you have a data array, you can loop through the columns and add a boolean flag on the max value using JavaScript, then use that flag in the code that renders the HTML to highlight the values.

Comment: This is not a static table. This is generated from database using `MySql` and `php`. But the problem is, the table is constructed by `rows`. So I can't save those values in an array to check what is the maximum value. If the table is constructed by `columns`, it will be easy to identify the max value in that column. But sadly, for my case, I cannot do that due to some other restrictions

Comment: How about this: loop through however many `<td>` elements you have, inside this loop for each index, loop through your `<tr>` elements, find the maximum, save its index, then highlight it, then move to the next `<td>` index.

Comment: @Anu I would suggest you change the title from *bootstrap table* to just *table*?

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar Okay...that is correct. I just changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  var highest = {};
  $('tbody td').each(function(i, td) {
     var index = $(td).index();
     highest[index] = Math.max(highest[index] || 0, parseInt($(td).text(), 10));
  });
  
  console.log(highest); // { 1: 12, 2: 65, 3: 90 }
});
```

Loop through each cell and find its `index` in the row and maintain a `highest` dictionary for every `index` in the row and check if current cell value is maximum or the previously stored one.

As a result, you will have an object indicating the highest for each column which you can use to highlight or do whatever is required. You might want to store the row index instead of highest value in the `highest` dictionary.

```
$(function() {
  var highest = {},
        highestValues = {};
      
  $('tbody td').each(function(i, td) {
    var colIndex = $(td).index() - 1;
    var rowIndex = $(td).parent().index();
    var currValue = parseInt($(td).text(), 10);

    if (currValue > (highestValues[colIndex] || 0)) {
      highest[colIndex] = rowIndex;
      highestValues[colIndex] = currValue;
    }
  });
  
  console.log(highest, highestValues);
  
  for(col in highest) {
    $('tbody tr').eq(highest[col]).find('td').eq(col).css('background', 'yellow');
  }
});
```

In case of multiple maximums, what you can do is to replace the part:

```
if (currValue > (highestValues[colIndex] || 0)) {
    highest[colIndex] = rowIndex;
    highestValues[colIndex] = currValue;
}
```

with:

```
var currHighest = highestValues[colIndex] || 0;

if (currValue > currHighest) {
    highest[colIndex] = [rowIndex];
    highestValues[colIndex] = currValue;
} else if(currValue === currHighest) {
    highest[colIndex].push(rowIndex);
}
```

And then, since we can have multiple rows which can have a maximum value, we would need to loop through each row in `highest[col]` so, replace the line:

```
 $('tbody tr').eq(highest[col]).find('td').eq(col).css('background', 'yellow');
```

with:

```
for(row in highest[col]) {
    $('tbody tr').eq(highest[col][row]).find('td').eq(col).css('background', 'yellow');
}
```

So, the final code would look like:

```js
$(function() {
  var highest = {},
    highestValues = {};

  $('tbody td').each(function(i, td) {
    var colIndex = $(td).index() - 1;
    var rowIndex = $(td).parent().index();
    var currValue = parseInt($(td).text(), 10);

    var currHighest = highestValues[colIndex] || 0;

    if (currValue > currHighest) {
      highest[colIndex] = [rowIndex];
      highestValues[colIndex] = currValue;
    } else if (currValue === currHighest) {
      highest[colIndex].push(rowIndex);
    }
  });
  
  for (col in highest) {
    for (row in highest[col]) {
      $('tbody tr').eq(highest[col][row]).find('td').eq(col).css('background', 'yellow');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Person 1</th>
        <th scope="col">Person 2</th>
        <th scope="col">Person 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Type 1</th>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>34</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Type 2</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Type 3</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>67</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is logging the highest values as key value pairs. But how can I access respective values and change colour? I tried to use `.css('background', 'yellow');`. But somehow I can't access the elements. Sorry I am not that familiar with `jQuery`

Comment: Alright...that works. It is really charming to see jQuery in action

Comment: There is a slight issue now. In case if multiple index have same value and if those are the maximum value, it is not highlighting all the values. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Anu You're right, if there are multiple maximums, it will settle for the first found. Let me see what I can do

Comment: @Anu Check the edits as I have added the support for multiple maximums.